# Making a GET request using Microsoft Excel for Facebook Graph data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, excel, get, vba

I'm trying to get metadata from Facebook Graph using a GET request, inside Excel

I am using Excel 2003

I have a column in Excel of 5,000 app_scoped_user_id's used in the Facebook Graph. I want to make a macro to extract the information from each Graph, which is found at https://graph.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id. Each Graph is a simple HTML page that reads as follows

```
{
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "first_name": "XXX",
    "gender": "XXX",
    "last_name": "XXX",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/XXX",
    "locale": "id_ID",
    "name": "XXX",
    "username": "XXX"
}
```

I wish to take this HTML for parsing so I can get each field into a cell next to the app_scoped_user_id in my Excel. Is there any way to do this as a GET request within Excel to dynamically get each row to look like this, based on the ID in the first column:

```
id | first_name | last_name | gender | link | locale | username
```

or simply

```
id | everything as a text string
```

Not sure how to write a script for this, I've tried to look up Microsoft.XMLHTTP to make a module inside the VBA editor but have no idea where to start

Thank you

Comment: That's not HTML but JSON, which is a javascript-based "data-transfer" notation.  Try googling "VBA JSON" for a few approaches on how to parse JSON in VBA.  You can use XMLHTTP to do the actual GET.

Comment: Thanks, Tim Williams

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, there is an example getting first 100 IDs. IMO in some cases it is not necessary to involve JSON parsing, `Split` function will do.

```
Sub GetSomeGraphData()
    Dim lId, lRow, aPattern
    aPattern = Array("id", "first_name", "last_name", "gender", "link", "locale", "username")
    lRow = 1
    ' example getting first 100 records
    For lId = 1 To 100
        If WriteGraphData(lId, lRow, aPattern) Then lRow = lRow + 1
        DoEvents
    Next
End Sub

Function WriteGraphData(lId, lRow, aPattern)
    ' lId - ID you want to get data for
    ' lRow - Excel sheet row where to write data
    ' aPattern - array containing the parameters to be written, in order
    ' returns: True - if at least one cell was populated with a value, False - in case of blank line
    Dim oXMLHttp, lCol, sProp, aTemp
    Set oXMLHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp")
    oXMLHttp.Open "GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/" & lId, False
    oXMLHttp.Send ("")
    lCol = 1
    WriteGraphData = False
    For Each sProp In aPattern
        aTemp = Split(oXMLHttp.ResponseText, """" & sProp & """: """)
        If UBound(aTemp) = 1 Then
            aTemp = Split(aTemp(1), """")
            Cells(lRow, lCol).Value = aTemp(0)
            WriteGraphData = True
        End If
        lCol = lCol + 1
    Next
    Set oXMLHttp = Nothing
End Function
```